# Apiary.io API Blueprint: Action Parameter enforcement for mock service

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

In my blueprint, I have an action parameter for the GET action that is defined as a required parameter. However when I invoke the mock service endpoint without the parameter I get a legal response. Is there any runtime enforcement corresponding to the defined action parameter constraints?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported. I've created a feature request for this over at http://support.apiary.io/forums/120125-general/suggestions/6657575-validate-parameters-in-the-mock-server.